# "12 Monkeys" tag

Tags: discussion

The tag [twelve-monkeys](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twelve-monkeys) applies to both the 1995 film and the later TV series, and its tag wiki says to use [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) and [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) to differentiate them.

- The movie and TV series are not actually named "Twelve Monkeys", but "12 Monkeys", although the movie is sometimes marketed as "Twelve Monkeys". The tag should probably be renamed.
- Should we split the tag into two tags, one for the movie and one for the book?

Comment: The film was released in various markets as "[Twelve Monkeys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuV83.jpg)"

Comment: @Valorum Interesting, I wasn't aware. Pretty sure the series wasn't though.

Answer (score 19):

### Use the usual naming strategy.

Simple. We should use our usual naming strategy for the film and call it [12-monkeys-1995](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/12-monkeys-1995)

<s>For the tv show I propose we leave it as [twelve-monkeys] since [twelve-monkeys-tv] looks silly.</s> We should call the TV show [twelve-monkeys-2015](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twelve-monkeys-2015) as that is coherent with our tag system for other shows (e.g. [the-flash-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-flash-2014)).

<sub>Swap "12" for "Twelve" as need be, I don't know what it really it should or would be called.</sub>

Comment: Yo, we *do* have tv-shows with that tag convention, see: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daredevil-2015. Also, I don't mind it.

Comment: Same with [the-flash-2014].

Comment: Sounds great. I think we should go with [tag:12-monkeys-2015] (which I have created and migrated the TV show questions to already) and [tag:12-monkeys-1995], and that [tag:twelve-monkeys] should be a synonym to the latter since the 1995 movie was apparently called _Twelve Monkeys_ in some markets.